# App stopping unexpectedly

Tags: android

My app is stoping unexpectedly and I cant find any app specific error logs.

This is the log I found when the app crahses  (com.corta.apptest is the packagename of the app):

```
    07-29 16:31:56.587 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/jdwp/jdwp_event.cc:681] Check failed: threadId != 0u (threadId=0, 0u=0) 
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Runtime aborting...
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Aborting thread:
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=2 WaitingForDebuggerSend (still starting up)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x0 self=0xb0209000
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=3571 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xaba52920
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=89 stm=19 core=1 HZ=100
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xab954000-0xab956000 stackSize=1022KB
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes= "abort lock"
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc 00572f1e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+238)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0053f30e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+526)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 0053c30b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+75)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 00527f13  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState10DumpThreadERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+67)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 00527ce7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+615)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 0051822b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+155)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 0011a5b3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD1Ev+1747)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 0039c280  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState19SetWaitForJdwpTokenEy+1328)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 0039b4e2  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState24AcquireJdwpTokenForEventEy+114)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 0039acf3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState29SendRequestAndPossiblySuspendEPNS0_9ExpandBufENS0_17JdwpSuspendPolicyEy+211)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #10 pc 003a0ec9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+1705)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #11 pc 001c2a85  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3Dbg16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+53)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #12 pc 001689fc  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11DefineClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEERKNS_7DexFileERKNS9_8ClassDefE+1116)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #13 pc 001683e9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker26FindClassInPathClassLoaderERNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEEPPNS8_5ClassE+1865)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #14 pc 0016979b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE+1163)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #15 pc 0014aca6  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11ResolveTypeERKNS_7DexFileEtNS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS4_INS5_11ClassLoaderEEE+182)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #16 pc 001a9c4c  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZNK3art19HInstructionBuilder25IsOutermostCompilingClassEt+908)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #17 pc 001a910d  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder16BuildNewInstanceEtj+1021)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #18 pc 001a1479  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder21ProcessDexInstructionERKNS_11InstructionEj+3593)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #19 pc 0019fd89  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder5BuildEv+2201)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #20 pc 0016fe90  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art13HGraphBuilder10BuildGraphEv+144)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #21 pc 001e5e1e  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZNK3art18OptimizingCompiler10TryCompileEPNS_14ArenaAllocatorEPNS_19CodeVectorAllocatorEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEjNS_10InvokeTypeEtjP8_jobjectRKS5_NS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+5342)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #22 pc 001e8888  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art18OptimizingCompiler10JitCompileEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_3jit12JitCodeCacheEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+632)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #23 pc 0015aaa0  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art3jit11JitCompiler13CompileMethodEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+400)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #24 pc 0015a8f7  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (jit_compile_method+55)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #25 pc 003b7cab  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3jit3Jit13CompileMethodEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadEb+539)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #26 pc 003ba190  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3jit14JitCompileTask3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+704)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #27 pc 0055d4eb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker3RunEv+91)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #28 pc 0055ccda  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker8CallbackEPv+106)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #29 pc 00074fe2  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #30 pc 0002029e  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #31 pc 0001e076  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   (no managed stack frames)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock mutator lock
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] All threads:
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] DALVIK THREADS (33):
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=2 Runnable (still starting up)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x0 self=0xb0209000
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=3571 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xaba52920
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=89 stm=20 core=1 HZ=100
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xab954000-0xab956000 stackSize=1022KB
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc 00572f1e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+238)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0053f30e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+526)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 0053c30b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+75)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0055befb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+1115)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 005521be  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList13RunCheckpointEPNS_7ClosureE+590)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 00551d32  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEb+962)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 00528168  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState14DumpAllThreadsERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+424)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 00527eb6  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+1078)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 0051822b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+155)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 0011a5b3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD1Ev+1747)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #10 pc 0039c280  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState19SetWaitForJdwpTokenEy+1328)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #11 pc 0039b4e2  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState24AcquireJdwpTokenForEventEy+114)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #12 pc 0039acf3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState29SendRequestAndPossiblySuspendEPNS0_9ExpandBufENS0_17JdwpSuspendPolicyEy+211)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #13 pc 003a0ec9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+1705)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #14 pc 001c2a85  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3Dbg16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+53)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #15 pc 001689fc  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11DefineClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEERKNS_7DexFileERKNS9_8ClassDefE+1116)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #16 pc 001683e9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker26FindClassInPathClassLoaderERNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEEPPNS8_5ClassE+1865)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #17 pc 0016979b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE+1163)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #18 pc 0014aca6  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11ResolveTypeERKNS_7DexFileEtNS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS4_INS5_11ClassLoaderEEE+182)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #19 pc 001a9c4c  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZNK3art19HInstructionBuilder25IsOutermostCompilingClassEt+908)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #20 pc 001a910d  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder16BuildNewInstanceEtj+1021)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #21 pc 001a1479  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder21ProcessDexInstructionERKNS_11InstructionEj+3593)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #22 pc 0019fd89  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder5BuildEv+2201)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #23 pc 0016fe90  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art13HGraphBuilder10BuildGraphEv+144)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #24 pc 001e5e1e  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZNK3art18OptimizingCompiler10TryCompileEPNS_14ArenaAllocatorEPNS_19CodeVectorAllocatorEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEjNS_10InvokeTypeEtjP8_jobjectRKS5_NS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+5342)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #25 pc 001e8888  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art18OptimizingCompiler10JitCompileEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_3jit12JitCodeCacheEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+632)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #26 pc 0015aaa0  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art3jit11JitCompiler13CompileMethodEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+400)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #27 pc 0015a8f7  /system/lib/libart-compiler.so (jit_compile_method+55)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #28 pc 003b7cab  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3jit3Jit13CompileMethodEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadEb+539)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #29 pc 003ba190  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3jit14JitCompileTask3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+704)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #30 pc 0055d4eb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker3RunEv+91)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #31 pc 0055ccda  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker8CallbackEPv+106)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #32 pc 00074fe2  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #33 pc 0002029e  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #34 pc 0001e076  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   (no managed stack frames)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x73d38f60 self=0xac60b400
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=3566 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb0976534
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=272 stm=21 core=1 HZ=100
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xbf1d6000-0xbf1d8000 stackSize=8MB
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_epoll_wait+0x23c/0x2d1
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_epoll_pwait+0x70/0xe1
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc ffffe424  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+16)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0007790b  /system/lib/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+43)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 00020cb0  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_pwait+112)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 00020d0e  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+62)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 00018f1b  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+203)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 00018d84  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+68)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 000d41f3  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjecti+77)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 000d4264  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 007b1c9c  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+136)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "Signal Catcher" prio=5 tid=3 WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c3d1f0 self=0xa2ac4e00
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=3572 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xab951920
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xab855000-0xab857000 stackSize=1014KB
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: do_sigtimedwait+0xd7/0x19f
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_rt_sigtimedwait+0x6e/0x9c
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc ffffe424  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+16)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 00077f51  /system/lib/libc.so (__rt_sigtimedwait+33)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 000289df  /system/lib/libc.so (sigwait+95)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0052eaeb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9SignalSet4WaitEv+59)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 0052e4b7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher13WaitForSignalEPNS_6ThreadERNS_9SignalSetE+215)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 0052c61a  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher3RunEPv+314)
    07-29 16:31:56.641 3566-3571/com.corta.apptest A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 00074fe2  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
```

This is a very generic error and it happens to me many times but I used to find app specific errors, but could not figure out the error here.

Update: 
This is happening when I scroll  up/down a recycler view ( and it happens very rarely). I am also using Rx java.

I could not put the whole log here please find the full stacktrace [here](https://pastebin.com/VV8WdWCY)

Comment: This is a native stack trace, indicating a problem in native code. If I am interpreting it propertly, ART seems to be having an issue with your code for some reason. Are you using anything unusual from a Java standpoint (e.g., lambda expressions)?

Comment: The only thing I suspect is RxJava.